# How do you get a Google Sheets column to update the grades of an existing Google Classroom posting?

Tags: google-sheets, google-classroom

### **How do I get a column of grades uploaded to an existing Google Classroom assignment using Google Sheets? How do I start?**

If there was a way to sync grade data in a Google Sheet up to an existing Google Classroom assignment? Is there a script or add-on?

Thanks.

### Some web tools can transfer Google Sheet data to the Google Classroom classwork.

- The "ImExClass" add-on can export grades while creating new coursework in the Google Classroom.
- The "Teacher Aide Pro" app can sync grade data between the app and the Google Classroom both ways, as long as the assignment was first made with the app.  Google Sheet data can be imported into the app and then synced with a Google Classroom classwork that was first made with the app. The developer also created the "Rubric Scorer" app, which creates a Google Classroom assignment and pushes grades out to that in a one-way direction.

These two developers above have been very good at replying to customer feedback.  They have been particularly helpful in providing feedback to address grade sync features for existing classwork directly created by the teacher in Google Classroom.

Comment: A.S.  It would help people work on your question if you could provide a sheet with sample data, editable by all, and showing what your outcome should look like.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't help you if you don't provide some previous research for your question, like for example some code or as @kirkg13 said, some sample data and an example data

Comment: Oh, thank-you.  I have updated the question body to include a Google Sheet link.

Comment: I haven't found a good answer for you yet.  There is an import grades option in Classroom, if those grades are based on a quiz you created with Google Forms, but not just grades from an external spreadsheet.  Good luck...

Comment: Thanks for following up and looking Kirkg13. Yes, that Google forms quiz option to import grades is a tool that I use. I know that one and it is a great feature. There is a way to tell each column on an external spreadsheet to speak to a specific Google Classroom posting that holds grades, but I haven't found that answer yet either. If I figure it out, then I'll probably send you a comment in celebration.

Comment: Just by chance I got an email today from Google Sheets blogger Yagisanatode,  titled "Google Apps Script: Upload grades into a Google Classroom Coursework Assignment".  This may help you some more.  See it here: https://yagisanatode.com/2020/05/13/google-apps-script-upload-grades-into-a-google-classroom-coursework-assignment/#more-3589

Comment: Just a warning - Yagisanatode states:  "One of the challenges of uploading grades to Google Classroom is that we can’t create an assignment in the Classroom dashboard and then upload grades directly to that assignment. Instead, we need to create the assignment programmatically. For us, we will do this in Google Apps Script."                          He repeats this warning.  I haven't yet found his reason that you can't update grades for coursework added via the console.

Comment: Thanks kirkg13.  That is a new posting!  Just today. I'm taking a look through it now.  I am halfway through the page and I am understanding what it is saying so far. I think I can do it. Thank you for sharing this. I'll make note of the challenge you highlighted.  I see that in the part written in there too and be mindful of that.